# show image in imageview from string in swift 4 without url

Tags: get, uiimage, swift4

I have a project in swift 4. I need to get an image from the api but I get error as "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?'".The codes of my project is:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {


  @IBOutlet weak var coachProfile: UIImageView!

   var responseArr = [JSON]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      getCoachList()
    }

  func getCoachList() {
    let url = "http://test.ilovecoach.com/api/student"
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let loader = appDelegate.showLoading()
    WebServices.sharedInstance.get(toURL: url, successHandler: { (jsonData) in
      print("messLists: \(jsonData)")
     self.responseArr  = jsonData.arrayValue
     loader.removeFromSuperview()
      let avatar = self.responseArr[0]["photo"].stringValue
       print("CoachAvatar",avatar) // gives: 12.png

      self.coachProfile.image = avatar //gives error as:Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?'

    }) { (error) in 
    }
  }
}
```

I have an get method api which gives response as :

```
[
    {
"name" : "Modi",
    "title" : "d'Etat",
    "id" : 12,
    "photo" : "12.png"
}
]
```

Now, I need to get image named "photo" to coachprofile imageview. How can I solve this in swift 4?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
self.coachProfile.image = UIImage(named: avatar)
```

Comment: it shows nil for the value of "self.coachProfile.image". @Carpsen90

Comment: @SwiftGuy do you have an image called "12.png" in your project? `UIImage(named:)` gives `nil` if there is no image with that name

Comment: "12.png" image is called from api get method. I don't have it in the project. @ Carpsen90